# What does EnumSet really mean?

Tags: java, object, enums, enumset

I have the following example:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SizeSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumSet largeSize = EnumSet.of(Size.XL,Size.XXL,Size.XXXL);
        for(Iterator it = largeSize.iterator();it.hasNext();){
            Size size = (Size)it.next();
            System.out.println(size);
        }
    }
}


enum Size {
  S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL;

}
```

In this code I can understand that the Enum creates an Enum type of Sizes.

My question is: is `largeSize` an object of EnumSet type? What does it really mean? I really want to understand it better.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As for any variable, its type is found in its declaration:

```
EnumSet largeSize
```

So yes, `largeSize` (which should be named `largeSizes` since it's a collection) is of type `EnumSet`. It should also be generified, and thus be declared as

```
EnumSet<Size> largeSizes
```

What it means, is that `largeSizes` is of type `EnumSet`. An `EnumSet` is a `Set` which contains enum instance of a specific enum type, in a more efficient way than other `Set` implementations (like `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, etc.). To know what an `EnumSet` is, read its [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

Comment: So it's kind of an Enum inside an Enum ? means another object (largeSizes) that represent part of an object (Sizes) ?

Comment: No, it's a set of enum values. `largeSizes` is a set which contains XL, XXL and XXXL. You could replace it with a HashSet, and it wouldn't change anything except performance and memory consumption. `Size` is not an object. It's a class. And this class defines several constants: L, XL, XXL, etc. of type `Size`.

Comment: I didn't understood it well... if Size (should be Sizes) is an object why it doesn't looks like: Enum Sizes = new Enum; ? and then the last 3 lines in the first code? If I can make a 'size' object of Size, means Size should be a Class....

Comment: `Size` should not be `Sizes`. XL is a `Size`, not a `Sizes`. `Size` is **NOT** an object. It's a class. `Size.XL` is one of the 6 instances of the class `Size`. Enums, by definition, are classes which only have a fixed number of instances (in this case, S, M, ... XXXL). You can't create a new instance of an enum, else it wouldn't be an enum anymore. `Size` **is** a class. All enums are classes, but defined in a different way.

Answer (score 49):

A simple `Enum` is a list of values that you can only select *one* from at a time. Using your example, a size can be only one of S, M, L, etc for any given clothing. You could use simple constants instead of the `Enum` but this has its advantages of readability, easier maintenance and strict type checking.

An `EnumSet` will be used when you have the need for a variable to assume more than one `Enum` value at the same time. For instance, a font you write to screen with can be both *bold* and *italic* at the same time. An `EnumSet` will allow you to add the various values and to test whether one of those is actually set at any given time. If you have come to Java from other programming languages, this is the functionality usually called **flags**.

Compare the two:

```
enum Size { S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL }
Size currentSize;
...
currentSize = Size.S;
...
if (currentSize == Size.S) ...
```

defines, assigns and then checks for a single `Enum` value.

```
enum FontStyle { Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough }
EnumSet<FontStyle> currentStyle;
...
currentStyle = EnumSet.of(FontStyle.Bold, FontStyle.Italic);
...
if (currentStyle.contains(FontStyle.Italic)) ...
```

defines, assigns two `Enum` values at the same time, then checks whether one of those is actually set or not.

Answer (score 41):

Simplifying your code

```
EnumSet<Size> largeSize = EnumSet.of(Size.XXXL, Size.XXL, Size.XL, Size.L);
for(Size size: largeSize)
    System.out.print(size+" ");
```

You can see that largeSize is a regular Set except its designed to store Enums.  How is that different?  Firstly the JVM knows all the possible values of the set which means instead of storing all the objects it can use a bitmap where 1 means the item is present and 0 means it is not.  This also means the order of the set is the order of the ordinal values i.e. the order they were defined.  This is why this prints

```
L XL XXL XXXL
```

If you want to know more detail I suggest you read the source for this class.

Answer (score 20):

From Joshua Bloch's book itself and in his own word:

> The java.util package provides EnumSet class to efficiently represent
>   sets of values drawn from a single enum type. This class implements
>   the Set interface, providing all of the richness, type safety and
>   interoperability you get with any other Set implementation. But
>   internally, each EnumSet is represented as a bit vector. If the
>   underlying enum type has sixty-four or fewer elements -- and most do
>   -- the entire EnumSet is represented with a single long, so its performance is comparable to that of a bit field. Bulk operations,
>   such as removeAll and retainAll, are implemented using bit wise
>   arithmetic, just as you'll do manually for bit fields. But you are
>   insulated from the ugliness and error-proneness of manual bit
>   twiddling. The EnumSet does the hard work for you.

So we can do something like this.

```
public class SizeSet {

  public enum Size {S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL}

  public void applySize(Set<Size> sizes){}

}
```

Client Code calling it might do something like

```
SizeSet largeSizeSet = new SizeSet();
largeSizeSet.applySize(EnumSet.of(Size.L, Size.XXL, Size.XXL));
```

Note that the applySize method takes the `Set<Size>` rather than an `EnumSet<Size>`. While it is pretty 
obvious and likely that the client would pass an EnumSet to the method, it is a good practice to accept an interface rather than the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 7):

EnumSet is specifically used for storing the enum type element and iterating over it quickly.
Eg.

```
for (Day d : EnumSet.range(Day.MONDAY, Day.FRIDAY))
        System.out.println(d);
```

The above snippet will display the days of the week from Monday through Friday.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

> Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient.

Readable, type safe, low memory footprint... What do you want more?

Answer (score 3):

Given the following example:

```
....
public static final String S = "s";
public static final String M = "m";
public static final String L = "l";
....

Set<String> sizeSet = new HashSet<String>();
sizeSet.add(S);
sizeSet.add(M);
```

so, what is sizeSet in the above example?

EnumSet is nothing different from the above example, only that EnumSet is a special Set implementation that works with and optimized with enum types, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

```
EnumSet largeSize
```

EnumSet largeSize is a set of Enum values which contains XL, XXL and XXXL.

```
Size
```

Size is a class of Enum type with constant values S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL.

```
largeSize.iterator()
```

The Iterator for EnumSet is in natural order, the order in which the values of the enum were originally declared.

- EnumSet class is a member of the Java Collections Framework & is not synchronized.
- Its a high performance set implementation, they are much faster than
  HashSet.
- All elements of each EnumSet instance must be elements of a
  single enum type.

To Know more read the api doc : [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html/)

Answer (score 0):

An `EnumSet` is a specialized **Set collection** to work with enum classes. It implements the `Set` interface and extends from `AbstractSet`:

[image]

When you plan to use an EnumSet youhave to take into consideration some points:

1. It can contain only enum values and all the values have to belong to
   the same enum
2. It doesn’t allow to add null values, throwing a NullPointerException in an attempt to do so
3. It’s not thread-safe, so
   we need to synchronize it externally if required
4. The elements are
   stored following the order in which they are declared in the enum
5. It uses a fail-safe iterator that works on a copy, so it won’t throw a
   ConcurrentModificationException if the collection is modified when
   iterating over it

Now, the `EnumSet largeSize` part is a **variable declaration** so yes, it's of type EnumSet. Please notice that you can add the type of elements in the collection for better type safety: `EnumSet<Size>`

Check out this article to [learn more about EnumSet](https://javatutorial.net/java-enumset-example).

Answer (score -2):

It quickly turn any Enum elements into a set, EnumSet is yet another type of Set.

```java
public enum Style { BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, STRIKETHROUGH }

EnumSet.of(Style.BOLD, Style.ITALIC);
```