# Creating List of Enums?

Tags: java, enums

So I have three enums and I want to make an ArrayList out of them.  Here's my code:

```
enum Outlook {
    SUNNY, RAINY, CLOUDY
}
enum Temperature {
    HOT, COLD, MILD
}
enum Humidity {
    HIGH, NORMAL, LOW
}
```

And I want my ArrayList to look something like:

```
{Outlook, Temperature, Humidity}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
ArrayList<Enum> attributes = new ArrayList<Enum>();
attributes.add(Temperature);
```

But already Eclipse tells me "Temperature cannot be resolved to a variable".  Any idea how to achieve what I'm aiming for here?

Comment: What is your final goal when doing this? What are you trying to accomplish? I'm asking because there is probably a better/cleaner solution.

Comment: You may want a `List<Class<? extends Enum<?>>>` and call `list.add(Temperature.class)`.

Comment: @assylias That seemed to work but what specifically does it do?

Comment: @gonzo I'm trying to have a collection of each of these enums (their classes I guess) so that I can call a function on each of them.  I'll basically loop through the collection, calling the function on each...

Comment: @AndyThomas I want to loop through all of the classes (Outlook, Temp, Humidity) and, for each of them, calculate information gain.  This is a function that makes use of each possible value of a given attribute (Outlook, Temp, Humidity).  Does that make sense?

Comment: ArrayList<Class<? extends Enum<?>>> attributes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Enum<?>>>();
  attributes.add(Outlook.class);
  attributes.add(Temperature.class);
  attributes.add(Humidity.class);
  attributes.add(Windy.class);
  attributes.add(Classification.class);                                                      Seems to work...not totally sure why I have to do .class though...

Comment: Is it the case that the outlook contains information about the temperature and humidity?

Comment: @Makoto no, it doesn't

Comment: Fair enough.  In that case, **what is the end goal**?  How do these elements relate to each other?  This is why I asked if outlook contained that information.  It sounds like you need another class to contain this information.

Comment: If order doesn't matter to you, have you looked at `EnumSet`?  Sounds like you're just trying to iterate.  Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825009/what-does-enumset-really-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surmising that you want the names of the enums themselves, and not their values. As such, try the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<Class<? extends Enum>> myEnums = new ArrayList<>();
    myEnums.add(Outlook.class);
    myEnums.add(Temperature.class);
    myEnums.add(Humidity.class);
    System.out.println(myEnums);
}

enum Outlook {
    SUNNY, RAINY, CLOUDY
}
enum Temperature {
    HOT, COLD, MILD
}
enum Humidity {
    HIGH, NORMAL, LOW
}
```

You can see the demo [here](http://ideone.com/XNDHCm) which will output:

```
[class Ideone$Outlook, class Ideone$Temperature, class Ideone$Humidity]
```

If you strictly need something like:

```
[Outlook, Temperature, Humidity]
```

and just can't like the extra `class Ideone$...` info then we can add some extra sophistication.

Comment: This is perfect.  Do you mind explaining the type of your arrayList?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what exactly you mean "*type of your ArrayList*" but I think that you're referring to the *Class<? extends Enum>* type. What you are really adding to the `ArrayList` are the class objects of the enums, themselves, and not their values. Each enum class extends the `Enum` class. So I'm basically saying: Create a list where the type is a *class* (not an object) where each added class is a Java enumeration. Let me know if that answer isn't sufficient or you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to loop through all of the classes (Outlook, Temp, Humidity) and, for each of them, calculate information gain. This is a function that makes use of each possible value of a given attribute (Outlook, Temp, Humidity).

One possibility would be to define a common interface implemented by all the attributes. This would allow your information-gain function to use the same interface regardless of attribute. And no reflection is required. For example:

```
interface IAttribute {
    Enum<?>[] getValues();
    String getName();
}
```

This interface applies to attribute classes as a whole, and not a particular attribute value. Here's one way to do that.

```
private static final class OutlookAttribute implements IAttribute {
    enum Outlook { SUNNY, RAINY, CLOUDY }

    @Override
    public Outlook[] getValues() { return Outlook.values(); }

    @Override
    public String getName() { return "Outlook"; }
}

// And similarly for Temperature and Humidity
```

Now you can create a list of attributes to pass to your function.

```
List<IAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
attributes.add( new OutlookAttribute() );
attributes.add( new TemperatureAttribute() );
attributes.add( new HumidityAttribute() );
```

And your function definition can iterate through attributes.

```
for ( IAttribute attribute : attributes ) {
   Object[] values = attribute.getValues();
   ...
   for ( Object value : values ) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which values to add:

```
attributes.add(Temperature.HOT);
attributes.add(Temperature.COLD);
```

`Temperature` all alone evaluates to a `class`, but your `ArrayList` can only contain `Enum`s (`Temperature.HOT`, `Humidity.HIGH`...)

Comment: Ah, but I actually want to be able to go through each Enum like {Outlook, Temperature, Humidity}...not the specific values each Enum can take...

Comment: So should I do an arrayList of classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the all values from a enum typ. Use Enumtyp.values().

```
public interface EnumInterface {
        public static enum Outlook {
            SUNNY, RAINY, CLOUDY
        }
        public static enum Temperature {
            HOT, COLD, MILD
        }
        public static enum Humidity {
            HIGH, NORMAL, LOW
        }
    }



    public class EnumImp {
        private static ArrayList<Enum> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addUnits() {
            EnumInterface.Outlook[] outlookValues = EnumInterface.Outlook.values();
            EnumInterface.Temperature[] temperatureValues = EnumInterface.Temperature.values();
            EnumInterface.Humidity[] humidityValues = EnumInterface.Humidity.values();

            for (int i = 0; i < outlookValues.length; i++) {
                list.add(outlookValues[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < temperatureValues.length; i++) {
                list.add(temperatureValues[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < humidityValues.length; i++) {
                list.add(humidityValues[i]);
            }

        }

        public void output() {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestEnum {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EnumImp e = new EnumImp();
            e.addUnits();
            e.output();
        }
    }
```

Comment: From the OP's comment [with emphasis added]: *"I want to loop through all of the **classes** (Outlook, Temp, Humidity) and, for each of them, calculate information gain."*