# Get an element from arrayList inside another class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a Staff class which contains a list of roles for that particular staff member. I also have staffList which holds the staff objects.

How do I get an element from the rolesList for that specific instance of the class?

I have tried:

```
staffList.get(0).getRolesList().get(0)
```

Which should be the first element of the rolesList from the first element of the staffList, but it just ruturns null.

I also tried:

```
rolesList.get(staffList.get(0))
rolesList.getIndexOf(staffList.get(0).getRolesList.get(0)
```

All return null

If I just get the value direct from the rolesList using get index it will display no problem.

I think it is getting a version of the rolesList but not the one that is in that particular Staff object

I have created a new Staff Member and a role in the roleList then used the list when I construct the staff object, so using the getRolesList method of that object and then get the index it should return the value from within the roleList but it isn't:

```
private List<Staff> staffList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Role> roleList = new ArrayList();
roleList.add(Role.DRIVER);
testDriver = new Staff("Mike", "Joy", roleList);
testStaffList.add(testDriver);
```

GetRolesList() Code

```
public List<Role> getRoleList() {
        return roleList;
    }
```

I basically want to get the stored Role from the objects rolelist within the testdriver object.

testDriver --> roleList --> Role.DRIVER (or whatever the Role happens to be)

Comment: As i can see on the last pieces of code, `staffList` is not related with the other objects at any point. Are you missing to paste something else?

Comment: Could you paste code from the `getRolesList()` function? It is unclear what the problem is without further examples of the code you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) We do not see the line of code adding `testDriver` to the `staffList`.

```
staffList.add( testDriver );
```

(b) You are missing parens on your call to `getRolesList`.

(c) You need to do some basic debugging. In the debugger or in extra code, look at:

- size of `staffList`
- Staff s = staffList.get(0)
- List roles = s.getRolesList()
- size of `roles`

Bonus tip… Apparently you are using an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for `Role`. If so, you should consider using an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) rather than a `List` for less memory usage and faster execution. `EnumSet` is a specialized implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). More discussion on [another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11825009/642706). Not part of your problem, just a tip.

```
Set<Role> roles = EnumSet.of( Role.DRIVER , Role.MECHANIC );
Staff testDriver = new Staff( "Mike" , "Joy" , roles );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give your full source..
That's not clear. I think u wanna add your staff object into staff list.. If it is

```
Stafflist.add(new Staff("a","b",role list));
```

Add all you want
Then try to get ..