# What is are the characteristics of EnumSets regarding class versioning?

Tags: java, enums

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) as well as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825009/what-does-enumset-really-mean) both emphasize on

> Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors.

Now I am wondering - what is the behaviour when sending (standard Java serialized) EnumSet objects over the wire to some *other* JVM that *might* have a different version of the underlying Enum class?

In other words: when I sent some `Set<MyEnum>` it is very well possible that an exception is thrown during de-serialization on the *other* JVM (in cases where *my* JVM is using some `MyEnum.NEW_GUY` that the *other* JVM doesn't know about). In that situation, the deserialization tries to instantiate an enum constant that doesn't exist in the class on the *other* JVM.

But assuming that EnumSet doesn't transport enum constant instances (but just a bit set with some bits true, some false) - what happens when the serialized EnumSet included `MyEnum.NEW_GUY`?

I tried to identify a specification that tells me what should happen ( versus assuming that this is an implementation detail ), but no luck so far.

Comment: _"But assuming that EnumSet doesn't transport enum constant instances"_ Looking at the source (JDK9), this is not the case. It uses a serialization proxy which saves the element type `Class` and an array of constants.

Comment: According to the source code: The bit vector is recalculated after reading an object from a stream. The serialization only writes an array of the enum values to the stream (besides the enum class). That means you can change the order of the enum values, and you also can add new enum values as long as you don't have them serialized in the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding implementation only (using Oracle Java 8), the answer is: it is not "just" a bitset.

Meaning: one can quickly write a test that serializes an EnumSet instance into a file, then change the enum class, and run code that reads back the set from the file.

Turns out:

- if the file contains an enum constant that doesn't exist any more, a `java.io.InvalidObjectException: enum constant B does not exist in class com.ibm.hwmca.z.managed.TestEnum` is thrown
- if all enum constants exist, but their order is changed - the set that gets read back is still correct.

In other words: that test suggests is that a serialized EnumSet does contain "more" information than just a plain bitset. The implementation is able to A) detect "missing" enum constants and B) deal with changes to the enum class that only affect the ordering of entries. Matching up with the comments by @Seelenvirtuose that the **serialized** EnumSet isn't a bit vector, but an array containing actual enum constants (thus being open for the exact same version conflict).

Still searching if there is a *specification* for the observed behavior.